micro-ros-agent error Not enough memory in the buffer stream
I'm using this test file for firmware for a pico which is connected to a RPi4 via USB. I'm using a debug probe attached to the pico with the USB going to a development Mac, and also using the micro_ros_raspberrypi_pico_sdk, branch foxy (this is pico_micro_ros_example.c from the GitHub repo):
#include <stdio.h>

#include <rcl/rcl.h>
#include <rcl/error_handling.h>
#include <rclc/rclc.h>
#include <rclc/executor.h>
#include <std_msgs/msg/int32.h>
#include <rmw_microros/rmw_microros.h>

#include "pico/stdlib.h"
#include "pico_uart_transports.h"

const uint LED_PIN = 25;

rcl_publisher_t publisher;
std_msgs__msg__Int32 msg;

void timer_callback(rcl_timer_t *timer, int64_t last_call_time)
{
rcl_ret_t ret = rcl_publish(&publisher, &msg, NULL);
msg.data++;
}

int main()
{
rmw_uros_set_custom_transport(
    true,
    NULL,
    pico_serial_transport_open,
    pico_serial_transport_close,
    pico_serial_transport_write,
    pico_serial_transport_read
);

gpio_init(LED_PIN);
gpio_set_dir(LED_PIN, GPIO_OUT);

rcl_timer_t timer;
rcl_node_t node;
rcl_allocator_t allocator;
rclc_support_t support;
rclc_executor_t executor;

allocator = rcl_get_default_allocator();

// Wait for agent successful ping for 2 minutes.
const int timeout_ms = 1000; 
const uint8_t attempts = 120;

rcl_ret_t ret = rmw_uros_ping_agent(timeout_ms, attempts);

if (ret != RCL_RET_OK)
{
    // Unreachable agent, exiting program.
    return ret;
}

rclc_support_init(&support, 0, NULL, &allocator);

rclc_node_init_default(&node, "pico_node", "", &support);
rclc_publisher_init_default(
    &publisher,
    &node,
    ROSIDL_GET_MSG_TYPE_SUPPORT(std_msgs, msg, Int32),
    "pico_publisher");

rclc_timer_init_default(
    &timer,
    &support,
    RCL_MS_TO_NS(1000),
    timer_callback);

rclc_executor_init(&executor, &support.context, 1, &allocator);
rclc_executor_add_timer(&executor, &timer);

gpio_put(LED_PIN, 1);

msg.data = 0;
while (true)
{
    rclc_executor_spin_some(&executor, RCL_MS_TO_NS(100));
}
return 0;
}

This builds with no errors and is transferred to the pico without errors either by using VSCode's debug or by an openocd transfer. I'm using the docker micro-ros-agent:foxy on the RPi4 starting it this way via an ssh terminal:
 $ docker run -it --privileged --rm --net=host microros/micro-ros-agent:foxy serial --dev /dev/ttyACM0 -v6

The agent starts without issues for a while, and then terminates with this error:
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'eprosima::fastcdr::exception::NotEnoughMemoryException'
 what():  Not enough memory in the buffer stream

I also note that the same termination error occurs when I try to 'ros2 topic list' from another machine on the network. This seems to be a known issue. The same behavior occurs even after the debug probe is disconnected. Is there a solution to this?

Can it be related to Resource Limits in QoS Policy?
According to this site The DataWriter’s write() call will block if it hits its resource limits, and one or more DataReaders have not received all the data. If the write() call times out without being able to send data, write() will return or throw an error.
